# how do i add multiple userSellers to this filter?

Tags: parse-platform, back4app

how do i add multiple userSellers to this filter? [image]

tried [“1234”,”5678”] [1234,5678] [1234,5678] add a bunch more

Answer (score 0):

to apply more filters, is necessary click at 'Add Filter' and select the additional conditions that you want :)

Comment: thanks but i will only let me do 1 userPointer filter. then the option is gone. i the box i tried ["user","user"] and a bunch of others. I thought  maybe since its a pointer i use could use <user><user> but that don't work either

Comment: :)
So, to read more about Pointers, Parse Server talk more about it: http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#one-to-many .
The pointer will be a reference to another, for example the class User with Session class.